# Correct SQL Statement returns correct row that represents front month expiry contract

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL server 2008 R2 database of trade records for several equity options, each at one minute intervals, and each minute contains records for several expiry. e.g.,

```
Symbol, TradeDate, Expiry, Open, High, Low, Close
AMZN, 4/01/2009 9:31:00, 4/17/2009, 8, 10, 9, 8.5
AMZN, 4/01/2009 9:31:00, 5/17/2009, 10, 11, 10, 11
AMZN, 4/01/2009 9:31:00, 6/18/2009, 12,13,12,12
GOOG, 4/01/2009 9:31:00, 4/17/2009, 8, 9, 7, 7.5
AMZN, 4/01/2009 9:32:00, 4/17/2009, 8.2, 8.9, 8.3, 8.5
AMZN, 4/01/2009 9:32:00, 5/16/2009, 3, 4, 4, 4
...
AMZN, 4/20/2009 9:31:00, 5/16/2009, 8.5, 9, 8.75, 8.75
AMZN, 4/20/2009 9:31:00, 6/18/2009, 9, 10, 9, 9.2
```

In options there is always a notion of the front month contract. For this problem, define the front month contract to be: If there are TradeDate entries less than the expiry date for that contract, that is the front month. Else, the front month is the next months contract. So for example, in the data above, on 4/01/2009, the AMZN front month is the contract that expires on 4/17/2009. However, when we move to TradeDate 4/20/2009, the front month is the 5/16/2009 contract since the 4/17/2007 contract expired over the weekend.

What is the SQL statement that would always return all the correct rows giving the "front month contract" based on what the TradeDate is?

Comment: Can you please add the EXPECTED output for the given example data. This will help me in determining what is it that you want and give you a correct query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you have described. The following query should do it. A self join :

```
SELECT T1.Symbol, T1.TradeDate, T1.Expiry, MIN(T2.expiry) AS FrontMonrhContract, T1.Open, T1.High, T1.Low, T1.Close FROM <TABLE> T1, <TABLE> T2 WHERE T1.TradeDate <= T2.Expiry GROUP BY T1.Symbol , T1.TradeDate, T1.Expiry
```

But it will not work if there is no entry for a trade of the FrontMonth Contract.
What i would feel better is that you either hand input a list of Expiries or compute them based on some rule, like last Friday of the month or something like that (if there is a rule). So that you do not risk miscalculating the front month if there is no trade for the frontMonth contract.

Better still do it in your application instead of SQL, as SQL is not meant for such work. In your application it would be a simple comparison with a list of expiries.
I have reduced execution time of a charting function which worked on data from a sqlite database by over 90% by doing such computations in the application itself instead of SQL.

**Update:**
Try the following query. It assumes the table name to be TRADES.

```
SELECT 
    T1.Symbol, 
    T1.TradeDate, 
    T1.Expiry, 
    MIN(T2.expiry) AS 'FrontMonrhContract' ,
    MIN(T1.[Open]) AS 'Open',
    MIN(T1.[High]) AS 'High',
    MIN(T1.[Low]) AS 'Low',
    MIN(T1.[Close]) AS 'Close'
FROM 
    TRADES T1, TRADES T2 
WHERE T1.TradeDate <= T2.Expiry AND T1.Symbol = T2.Symbol
GROUP BY T1.Symbol , T1.TradeDate, T1.Expiry
```

I just built a sample table with the data you provided in the question and this query works as expected on that data set. For note I have SQL Server 2005

**Update 2:**
To optimize the execution of the query, try adding an Index with the three GROUP BY columns `Symbol, TradeDate, Expiry` in that order.
I created a query execution plan and over 60% time is for resolving the GROUP BY, and after adding this index in my sample db it was completely gone.

Comment: There is only one table, not two. I assume that is what you mean by T1 and T2.

Comment: Yes there is one <TABLE>, its a self join, that is a join of a table with itself. T1 and T2 are aliases for the same table so we can unambiguously refer to the columns needed. So in the above query <TABLE> will be replaced by the name of your trades table in BOTH places.

Comment: Thanks. Now that I see how to actually build the query correctly, this does not work. I get entries on 2009-04-01 09:31:00.00 for both the 2009-04-18 and 2009-05-16 expiry (and others but just to keep it simple.) Unless I have not been clear on what I am trying to accomplish. For each minute of each day, there is a unique front month contract.

Comment: Oh wait, the symbol FrontMonthContract DOES have the correct contract! Sorry, I was looking at the other fields. Now I am wondering how I return only those records whose date are less than or equal to the current FrontMonthContract. So the query results look like this: AAPL       2009-04-01 09:31:00.000 2009-04-18 00:00:00.000 2009-04-18 00:00:00.000 104.137
AAPL       2009-04-01 09:31:00.000 2009-05-16 00:00:00.000 2009-04-18 00:00:00.000 104.097

Comment: For example, the query returns two rows per FrontMonthContract. CompSymbol, TradeDate, Expiry, FrontMonthContract, SecretSauce AAPL       2009-04-01 09:31:00.000 2009-04-18 00:00:00.000 2009-04-18 00:00:00.000 104.137
AAPL       2009-04-01 09:31:00.000 2009-05-16 00:00:00.000 2009-04-18 00:00:00.000 104.097

Comment: I just built a sample table and tried the query, i have updated my answer with the working query, give it a try.

Comment: Also don't forget to mark my answer as the accepted answer if it solves your problem. You can do this by clicking on the empty tick on left side of my answer below the vote count.

Comment: It doesn't work. I get two entries per minute for each symbol, the frontmonth, and the next month :-(( What you would like to say is: WHERE T1.TradeDate <= FrontMonthContract AND T1.CompSymbol = T2.CompSymbol But I get an error when I try that.

Comment: For example, on the example data in the original question, I would get [at least] the first two rows for AMZN.

Comment: DanishGoel I apologize, this does seem to work. I am confused why it seemed to give a different result before? One thing, this query is going to take a week to complete - it is taking about an hour to deal with one day! I don't know if there is a way to optimize the query. Maybe the huge amounts of data (about 200 GB compressed) is wrong for this.